# Difference in time doesnot work in python. The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

df['DiffTime']=df['time1']-df['time2']

i am trying to do difference of date and it brings up and error

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

My difference time is in format - "0 days 00:53:39"
i tried to use below to make a condition for 30minutes and above

```
if d['fDiffTime']>numpy.timedelta64(3219000000000,'ns'):
    
    display(df)

Also tried this

if d['fDiffTime']>0 days 00:30:00
```

Is there a way i can avoid all these and get difference time greater than 30 minutes

```
if d['fDiffTime']>numpy.timedelta64(3219000000000,'ns'):
    
    display(df)

Also tried this

if d['fDiffTime']>0 days 00:30:00
```

Is there a way i can avoid all these and get difference time greater than 30 minu

Comment: Please post a short (a few lines) but complete Python script which gives you the error. Also, please post the entire message (all lines) you get.

Answer (score 0):

To get a time difference in say minutes use:

```
df['DiffTime']=(df['time1']-df['time2'])/ pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
```

else use (hours = 1) or (days = 1) as required.